# Finding the position of controls in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in a window application. I want to perform some action on the hover of any control on the webpage opened in the webbrowser control in my application. Please suggest how can i do this. Actually i want to read out the focused control text but don't have any idea about that. Please provide me some useful tips and trick .

Comment: hover event is usually defined using Javascript, have you tried it to work around with it? What have you tried in your windows form?

Comment: yes, but i want to call c# code function, because i want to read the text or inner html of the control .

Answer (score 0):

Win app?
you can try below to get control obj

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

```
    {
        //this.Capture = true;   
        Control cc = this.GetChildAtPoint( new Point(e.X, e.Y ) );
        if (cc != null)
            this.Text = cc.Text;
    }
```

if you want to get other app's obj
http://www.builder.com.cn/2007/1020/568176.shtml

Comment: no this will not work, i had already tried it, it will only work for the controls on the from not in the webbrowser control. Thanks to resoopnse